# asp.net with oracle connectivity issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle11g, database-connection

I am trying to add parameters using oracle as database using the following code
:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
    var parameterName = ":ref_cur" + i;
    DbParameter parameter = Acidaes.Data.DbHelper.CreateRefCursorParameter(
        parameterName, 
        ParameterDirection.Output);
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
}
```

Following Crash occurs while adding parameters

> [A]Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter cannot be cast to [B]Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter. Type A originates from 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.DataAccess\2.112.2.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll'. Type B originates from 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.112.2.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll'.

Didn't find way to resolve this crash.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check your references, there is a mismatch in the versions you are looking at:

```
DbParameter parameter = 
 Acidaes.Data.DbHelper.CreateRefCursorParameter(parameterName, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

`DbParameter` as referenced in your code is not of the same type (version in this case) as what is being returned from your `DbHelper` class.  You will need to update these two projects to refer to the same version of `Oracle.DataAccess`.

Comment: No worries - if you hit the tick at the side of the answer, it will let people know that this answer was 'correct'.